# Has any EU directive related to "solidarity tax" been discussed and approved after 2015?

Tags: european-union, romania

According to [this article](https://www.romania-insider.com/solidarity-tax-controversies-romania/), Romanian finance minister justified a "solidarity tax" by existence of a European Directive that forces the state to implement such a tax:

> The minister announced on Wednesday evening, in a TV show, that all
>   employers would pay a tax amounting to 2% of their wage costs,
>   starting January 2018. He argued that the tax is requested in an
>   European directive that all member states must implement.

However, I cannot find any reference to such a directive. I have only found a reference about some discussions about it [here](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-europe-migrants-tax/germany-eu-deny-report-on-european-solidarity-tax-idUSKCN0S408120151010), but this seems to be refugees related:

> “The fact remains: we don’t want tax increases in Germany or to
>   introduce an EU tax,” government spokesman Steffen Seibert said in a
>   statement.
>
> A spokesman for the European Commission also dismissed the report.
>   “There is no such proposal currently on the table or under
>   preparation,” he said, adding the Commission never comments on rumors
>   in the press.

**Question:** Has any EU directive related to "solidarity tax" been discussed and approved after 2015?

Comment: There is no such proposal in Germany, so no. And note that your article is from 2015. And "the EU" can impose no community-wide tax.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - yes, I know the article is old, but I could not find any other source to link to the minister's declaration. My feeling is that he used a very poor justification to introduce a new tax.